# How to multiply elements of $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space by a complex scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this exercise from Linear Algebra Done Wrong:
[image]

1. If I “identify” a complex number $x + iy$ with a vector $(x, y)^T$ then does multiplying by a complex scalar $\alpha = a + ib$ result in the vector $(\alpha x, \alpha y)^T$ or in the vector $(ax - by, ay + bx)^T$?
2. In (b), I don’t understand what it means to multiply by $\alpha = a + ib$ if we treat $\mathbb{C}$ as a *real* vector space, if in a *real* vector space the scalars are real numbers and not complex numbers.

If someone could offer some insights on these questions I would appreciate it!

Comment: The word "multiplication" in this problem means "complex multiplication" in every instance.  In (b), the complex multiplication isn't the same as the scalar multiplication of the real vector space structure, but it's still a perfectly reasonable transformation.

Comment: @NateEldredge How can you multiply by a complex number in a real vector space, as in (b)? Doesn’t “real vector space” mean the scalars can only be real numbers, not complex numbers?

Comment: In general you cannot.  But when that real vector space happens to be $\mathbb{C}$, you already know how to do complex multiplication, so just do it.

Comment: So to clarify explicitly: for 1, the second option you give is correct.

Comment: Well, yes and no.  I think you are going to get confused in (1) if you identify a complex number with a pair $(x,y)$, because that makes it $\mathbb{C}$ look like a real vector space of dimension 2, whereas you really want to think of it here as a complex vector space of dimension 1.  Indeed the answer to (a) is extremely trivial...

Comment: You are only identifying $x + iy$ as $(x,y)^T$ in parts 2 and 3.  By writing $(x,y)$ instead of $x + iy$, you are already "treating $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space".  Nevertheless, the formula you give for multiplying by $a + ib$ is fine

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In (a), multiplication by $a + ib$ maps $1 \mapsto a + ib$ and $i \mapsto -b + ia$, then the matrix should be $\begin{bmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$, is that right? However in (b), I still don’t understand how I can multiply a complex number $\alpha = a + ib$ by a vector $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium That is true for part (b), but not for part (a).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I’m having a hard time understanding why that’s true. If we have as in (a) just the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}$, isn’t it true that $\{1, i\}$ form a basis and multiplication by $a + ib$ maps $1$ and $i$ as in my comment above? If possible, would you mind expanding on this more?

Comment: @NateEldredge In (a), is the matrix just $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium: For (a), the set $\{1,i\}$ is not a basis, because it is not linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$: there is a nontrivial complex linear combination of these two elements that vanishes. Namely, $i 1 + (-1) i$.

Comment: @NateEldredge That makes sense, thank you. In (b), should I just be thinking of multiplication by $\alpha = a + ib$ as the map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(x, y)^T \mapsto (ax - by, ay + bx)$, which like you said is a perfectly fine transformation? I was just hung up on the fact that $\alpha$ being a complex number is not in the field of scalars but what you’re saying makes sense to me now.

Comment: @TheProofisTrivium: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106022/discussion-between-theproofistrivium-and-nate-eldredge).